# facing an issue using regex to replace all punctuation in a file

Tags: java, regex

I'm tasked with excluding all non-alphanumeric values from a file and converting it to lowercase in Java. Currently, I'm using the following

```
replaceAll("\\p{P}+","").toLowerCase();
```

However, this excludes all but the ` type of quotation mark. Could someone please tell me how I could exclude this type of a quotation mark as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtick (`) character, aka [Unicode Character 'GRAVE ACCENT' (U+0060)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm), is categorized as `Symbol, Modifier [Sk]`.

The `Symbol` [Unicode Categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) include:

- [Symbol, Currency [Sc]](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/index.htm)
- [Symbol, Modifier [Sk]](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sk/index.htm)
- [Symbol, Math [Sm]](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/index.htm)
- [Symbol, Other [So]](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/index.htm)

If you want to replace those too, change regex to:

```
replaceAll("[\\p{P}\\p{S}]+","") // Punctuation or Symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `{Punct}` instead of `{P}`.